# How to get Google spreadsheet time zone offset string instead of timezone string?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone, simpledateformat, timezone-offset

Google sheet spreadsheet have a time zone setting viewed via the File -> Settings menu. see image.
[image]
However following code line

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
```

returns: **America/New_York**

I'd like to get using app script the time zone string as it appears in the file setting (**(GMT-5) Eastern Time**) rathen than as it is returned by `getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat` from `Utilities.formatDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
const t_so70410789 = ()=>{
  const t = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const f = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),t,`'(GMT'XXX')' zzzz`)
  console.log(f);
}
```